# Recursive vs. non-recursive implementations of Fibonacci sequence

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci-sequence

I have 2 functions to get the n-th fibonacci number. The 1st one uses recursive calls to calculate the power(M, n), while the 2nd function uses iterative approach for power(M, n). Theoretically (at least what I think), they should have the same speed O(log n), but why when I run both, the 2nd one is much slower than the 1st one?

```
def fib_1(n):
    from numpy import matrix
    def power(F, n):
        if n == 0 or n == 1: return matrix('1 1; 1 0', object)

        F = power(F, n >> 1) # n // 2
        F = F * F
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return F
        if n % 2 != 0:
            return F * matrix('1 1; 1 0', object)

    F = matrix('1 1; 1 0', object)
    F = power(F, abs(n)-1)
    return F[0,0] if n > 0 else int((-1)**(n+1)) * F[0,0]
```

```
def fib_2(n):
    from numpy import matrix
    def power(F, n):
        M = matrix('1 1; 1 0', object)
        while n > 0:
            if n & 1 == 1:
                M = F * M
            n = n >> 1 # n = n // 2
            F = F * F
        return M

    F = matrix('1 1; 1 0', object)
    F = power(F, abs(n)-2)
    return F[0,0] if n > 0 else int((-1)**(n+1)) * F[0,0]
```

Comment: Please share how you profile. In my setup, `fib_2` is _much_ faster.

Comment: @vnp, for small numbers, fib_2 is totally faster, but for big n (like n=2,000,000), fib_2 is much slower. I just use a normal start_time = time.perf_counter() and end_time to see the time they took to complete calculating a big n fib

Answer (score 6):

Before we got any further, a word of warning. The complexity is only valid in a particular computational model.

The complexity of these algorithms is \$O(\log n)\$ *only* if the addition takes constant time. For large \$n\$ it is not the case.

Fibonacci numbers grow exponentially with `n`. It means that the number of bits grows linearly. Now we are in the Turing machine realm. The last addition itself takes \$O(n)\$, which is way more than \$\log n\$.

The overall complexity should be \$O(n\log{n})\$ in both cases. Why the two exhibit different performance?

The *likely* reason is that there is a subtle difference between them. `fib_1` maintains just one matrix, `F`. `fib_2` maintains two of them, `F, M`, and must do roughly twice as many reallocations as `fib_1` does. The matrices contain huge numbers, and I expect that the memory management time dominates. Yet another factor the computational model shall now consider.

Answer (score 3):

Before some more detailed performance analysis, it's important to note some low-hanging fruit in terms of code quality.

### Global imports

Unless you have a really good reason, `from numpy import matrix` should be at the top of the file in global scope.

### Deprecated library classes

[`matrix` is deprecated](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html). Use `ndarray` instead.

### Do not reconstruct constants

`matrix('1 1; 1 0', object)` should not be parsed and reconstructed every time. Save it outside of function scope. If you need it to be modified later, modify a copy. Copying will be cheaper than parsing.

### Redundant branches

In this:

```
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return F
    if n % 2 != 0:
        return F * matrix('1 1; 1 0', object)
```

The second `if` is not necessary because its condition is guaranteed to be `True`.

### Expression simplification

```
int((-1)**(n+1))
```

It's probable that `n` is already an integer based on how your function is set up (though documentation and/or type hints would help to clarify this). The fact that a `float` is produced when the exponent is negative is probably due to Python assuming that it effectively needs to do a division, which is reasonable. All things considered, rather than doing the exponentiation - which is common in pure math, because of simplicity of analysis - you should consider doing the "piece-wise" thing instead. Rather than

```
return F[0,0] if n > 0 else int((-1)**(n+1)) * F[0,0]
```

consider

```
y = F[0,0]
if n <= 0 and n%2 == 0:
    y = -y
return y
```

Comment: On the last point, I don't know why but if the result is negative (-1), it's cast to -1.0. That's why I had int cast there

Comment: I just tried this and it gave me -1.0 ```n = -10
print((-1)**(n+1))```

Comment: @Reinderien When the exponent is integer, there are no roots involved. For negative integers it is the division.

Comment: Yes, that. Negative exponent is "one over" not "root".

Comment: `return F[0,0] * (1 if (n > 0 or n%2) else -1)` keeps it in 1 line, and is clearer than both in my opinion

Comment: Re. the root/division - that's right; I've edited it.

Comment: @MaartenFabré Re. the ternary-golfed statement - you're entitled to your opinion; I think the `if` is clearer.